# unity スクロール

Tags: unity3d

unityでスクロールバーを使い画面を横にスクロールしたいと考えています
縦のスクロールはできたのですが横のスクロールがわかりません
そしてタッチではなくスクロールバーで画面を横スクロールするやり方がわからないので教えていただきたいです
言語はC#で書いています

Answer (score 1):

uGUIでの実装なら、
ScrollbarにDirectionというプロパティがあるので、そちらを切り替えてみたらどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ヒエラルキーを右クリックし、UI > Scroll View を選択すると、最初から縦と横のスクロールバーのついたオブジェクトが生成されると思います。
それを参考に自分でも設定してみるのはどうでしょうか。
（ScrollRectのインスペクタのHorizontal Scrollbarが、横方向スクロールバーの参照です）
ちなみに、そのままではContent以下の大きさに合わせてスクロールバーが自動で消えますが、ScrollRectの設定を変更することで出しっぱなしにもできます。